# Macbook Air doesn't load my React App

Tags: macos, reactjs, loading

I have a very strange question, and I apologize in advance for the vagueness. I have a react app that seems to work on all machines that I've tried it on *except* macbook air computers from 2014 through 2016. This seems very strange to me, so much so that I don't know how to boil down the question on why there is a problem much further than that. Is there a known bug or something else that is going wrong that would cause this to be an issue? If anyone who has a macbook air, or may be interested in seeing the bug, the repo for my site is here: https://github.com/patientplatypus/professional_portfolio_retrofuturism. Please let me know if you have any thoughts. Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean running it locally or navigating to the app through the browser? If it's local development, then there could be tons of reasons. I would start by making sure the versions of node and npm that are on a working machine are on the macbook air as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running into a problem with ES6 support: http://www.webbrowsercompatibility.com/es6/desktop/

You may want to add `babel-polyfill` to your app to help address older browsers: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-polyfill